# Should an SP or IdP prefer Redirect or POST when both are available?

Tags: saml

For AuthnRequest, Response, and LogoutRequest, if Redirect and POST are supported (per metadata), should one be preferred over another?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Most commonly***, Requests can be either, but Responses are POST. This is driven by security and size of the Assertion.

**Security**: if using redirect, the Response is part of the URL. As such, it can be captured in various logs, as noted in the security considerations of the spec, specifically Section 3.4.5.2 [lines 670-1 of saml-bindings](http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-bindings-2.0-os.pdf#page=19).

**Size**: some enterprises send a large number of attributes, including big sets of groups. I've even seen avatars sent in assertions. This can make the size of the response very large, and in some cases, can overwhelm the browser's allowed URL size.

If neither of these are of concern, then either can be used.

Comment: I get that they can be either and that message size may require POST, but if both are available and feasible, which should be used? I'm not entirely sure I buy the security argument against Redirect since an intermediate device sees the entire HTTP payload, not just URL, and there is an implication that the messages are not signed or that the signing method is insecure. If POST is the remedy, there might be a bigger problem.

Comment: I hadn't had enough coffee when I answered. Added a link to the specific security consideration difference that I meant (not intermediate, but `referer` capture). Hope that my edits help. If not, let me know. :)

Comment: Ok, that makes more sense. If this can really happen in the wild, it would seem to make Redirect extremely insecure, especially since https would offer no protection. Thanks.

Comment: It really depends on what you're passing for subject and attributes. If it's an opaque identifier, then it's not likely to be an issue. If it's got the username and email, maybe you use POST.  If it contains PII then maybe you not only use POST but you encrypt, as well.